# How to hide PivotItem Header?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I wish to have a Pivot control that has PivotItems but no pivot item Header text in landscape (it's a gallery in landscape mode, when reverted to portrait it should display the PivotItems header again).

The solution to make the text `PivotItem.Header = ""` is not good since the space occupied by the header text is still reserved (so there's a blank space that is not used).

How can I do so?

Comment: Set the HeaderTemplate.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239071/wp7-pivotcontrol-set-header-null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the top `Margin` of your pivot items to a negative value to move them up:

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="item1" Margin="0,-100,0,0">
```

It doesn't remove the header, but your gallery items will be on top of it and thus have more space available. Combine this with your idea of clearing the captions and you could have a solution.

Answer (score 3):

A more elegant solution: just override the deafult HeaderTemplate with a non-visibile (but NOT collapsed) DataTemplate:

```
<controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Height="0" Width="0">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: This is a solution for Pivot.Header, that does not apply to PivotItem.Header

Answer (score 0):

You can first save headers of all pivotitem, then set all the pivotitems' header to empty string, after that, all the pivothead region will disappear. you can restore them using the saved header information.

```
  private void ResotorePivotItemHeaders()
    {
        if (_pivotItemHeaders.Count == pivot.Items.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _pivotItemHeaders.Count; i++)
                (pivot.Items[i] as PivotItem).Header = _pivotItemHeaders[i];
        }
    }



    private void HidePivotItemHeaders()
    {
        if (pivot.Items.Count == 0)
            return;
        _pivotItemHeaders.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i<pivot.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            PivotItem item = pivot.Items[i] as PivotItem;
            _pivotItemHeaders.Add(item.Header as String);
            item.Header = "";
        }
    }
   List<String> _pivotItemHeaders = new List<string>();
```

Comment: It still takes the Tab Event and shows Focus