# Hiding and showing a databound PivotItem header during runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-7.1

I think the present implementation of PivotItem is somewhat inconsistent not to say flawed. If the property Header is set before or after it has been rendered completely the size of the header is set appropriately, however, setting the Header back to null or string.empty does not cause the header to shrink again. Is there an elegant way of hiding and showing a PivotItem header when the Header is set via DataBinding or can a PivotItem be forced to revalidate it's boundaries?

As of now I'm trying "solve" my problem with some rather crude code which includes Events and the complete recreation of the Pivot programmatically and then attach all the PivotItems again. Maybe an OK solution for just page, but certainly somewhat iffy when this needs to be done 10+ times.

[This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008385/how-to-hide-pivotitem-header) in a [somewhat similiar context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239071/wp7-pivotcontrol-set-header-null), but was never really solved.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that changing the Visiblity or reducing the header height of a PivotItem simply doesn't work (yet?) on an already rendered item. It's simply broken, but it is possible to circumnavigate those shortcomings by moving the first child element of a PivotItem through changing its top margin to a negative value. Admittedly not elegant, but working. Here is some code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:SubtitleConverter x:Key="SubtitleConverter" />
    <local:MarginConverter x:Key="MarginConverter" />       
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<controls:PivotItem Name="LayoutItem" Header="{Binding Path=MyProgramSettings.ShowHeader, Converter={StaticResource SubtitleConverter}}">
    <ListBox Margin="{Binding Path=MyProgramSettings.ShowHeader, Converter={StaticResource MarginConverter}}"> 
        <!-- element that is moved up and down depending on some property -->
    </ListBox>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

Code behind

```
public class SubtitleConverter : ConverterBase
    {
        public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {   
            /* should always return a non empty string, making the PivotItem header height predictable */
            /* needed for MarginConverter */
            return MyProgramSettings.ShowHeader ? " " : MyResource.SomeText.ToLower();
        }
    }

    public class MarginConverter : ConverterBase
    {
        public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool && (bool)value)
            {
                return new Thickness(12, 0, -28, 0);
            }
            return new Thickness(12, 0, -12, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to remove the header for only one item while keeping the other headers? If so, I would not recommend this. It would be very confusing.

If trying to collapse all of them, you can bind the visibility of the PivotHeaderTemplate to a few things. One is the DataContext of your page

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="MyPivot" >
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Visibility="{Binding DataContext.HeaderVisibility, ElementName=MyPivot}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraExtraLarge}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

Then you could have a HeaderVisibility property in the viewmodel of your page.

If you want to set the text to null of the headers, you can use a value converter

xaml:

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="MyPivot" >
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraExtraLarge}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

And the converter:

```
public class TextToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return Visibility.Collapsed;

        return (string.InNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shawn for your feeback. I'm trying to hide or show all PivotItem headers at once. Setting the visibility (or a negative top margin) directly or via data-binding before the elements are rendered does work and I tried it. However, during runtime I'm only able to increase the space the header uses and setting the visibility to Visibility.Collapse, setting the content to null or setting the Margin property to a certain Thickness with a negative top value does nothing except hiding or repositioning of the text. Meaning the space it took at the first rendering will still be occupied.

Comment: I believe the first solution should work for you (binding visibility). Is this not working?

Comment: I tried both, but unfortunately they are not working. They will make the header disappear, but will leave a big empty space behind. In the meantime I came up with another fix that is rather wacky, but is working and maybe slightly more elegant than recreating the Pivot completely: First I'm binding the header of the PivotItem to a string property with the help of a converter that will never return an empty string. Even in cases it should be empty I'm returning a string with a whitespace and therefore the header is always rendered and of a certain height.

Comment: The last step is binding the Margin of the PivotItem to the same string property. In cases the header should be hidden it will simply be negative for the Top property depending on the font size used in the header. Basically I set the Header to an empty text and let the PivotItem move upwards simulating the hiding. Will post some code later...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried also binding the pivot's header height to a property that updates as your header text is set to empty/null (value 0?)

If that works, maybe another thing you could try is binding the Height property to the same value as your header text, along with a converter (pseudo: if text is null then return 0 for height) - that way you don't have an extra property to worry about.

Comment: Would indeed be a very neat solution, but I couldn't find any Pivot Header property. Could you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Great idea!
I don't use your solution exact, but I was inspired by your idea.

Here is what I did:

1.Create a StackPanel as a container, set the top margin with negative value, such as `Margin="0,-35,0,0"`

2.Add a few TextBlocks to fake the Pviot Headers, set data binding that you was intended to bind with the Headers.

3.Set TextBlocks `Width = "Auto"`, add a few right Margin so it won't be too crowded

NOTE: When the first TextBlock represent the current PivotItem, the others represent the others -- which are in-activated.

4.For the TextBlocks for in-activated PivotItems, we set the `Foreground="#FF727272"` to make a distinguish with the activated one. And also add a Event Handler, e.g. `Tap="GoToPivot2_Tap"` with the simple code behind: `PivotRoot.SelectedItem = Pivot2;`

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="PivotRoot">

    <controls:PivotItem x:Name="Pivot1">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,-35,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header1}" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" FontSize="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header2}" Tap="GoToPivot2_Tap" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" Foreground="#FF727272" FontSize="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header3}" Tap="GoToPivot3_Tap" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" Foreground="#FF727272" FontSize="30"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </controls:PivotItem>

    <controls:PivotItem x:Name="Pivot2">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,-35,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header2}" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" FontSize="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header3}" Tap="GoToPivot3_Tap" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" Foreground="#FF727272" FontSize="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header1}" Tap="GoToPivot1_Tap" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" Foreground="#FF727272" FontSize="30"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </controls:PivotItem>

    <controls:PivotItem x:Name="Pivot3">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,-35,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header3}" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" FontSize="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header1}" Tap="GoToPivot1_Tap" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" Foreground="#FF727272" FontSize="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header2}" Tap="GoToPivot2_Tap" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" Foreground="#FF727272" FontSize="30"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

That's it.

Maybe event less elegant than yours, but also works.